# asp.net core application docker swarm hosted client IP

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-swarm, docker-network

I want to log my client's requests IP address and I have a docker service of asp.net core on Linux.
now we always have docker network IP address! 
how can I get my clients real IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the real IP address of the clients if you change your mode to `host`. Below is an example of how to do this:

```
 traefikedge:
    image: traefik:1.4.3-alpine
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80 #for redirect to HTTPS
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host #to bypass ingress mesh, to preserve client ip
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host  #to bypass ingress mesh, to preserve client ip
```

There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25526) about this.

Comment: isn't possible without host mode ?

Comment: @sadeghhp only if you have a proxy in front of it like `nginx`

Comment: why docker cant forward headers like other loadbalancers?

Comment: @sadeghhp I suppose the level is too low, at TCP level. There is an open issue about this.